# Prove that if $G$ has $\pi_k$ property then $deg(v) \geq k$ for $v\in V(G)$

Tags: graph-theory

Let $k$ be a fixed integer.

> A graph $G$ of order $n$ and size $m$ has property $\pi_k$ if
>
> 1. $m=kn-\binom{k+1}{2}$;
> 2. for every induced subgraph of order $p$ and size $q$ in $G$, it follow that $q\leq kp-\binom{k+1}{2}$.
>
> a) Prove that if $G$ has $\pi_k$ property, then $\deg(v) \geq k$ for each $v\in V(G)$.
>
> b) Prove that if $G$ has $\pi_k$ property, then $\omega(G) \leq k+1$.

I'm trying to practice to prepare for my final exam, so I do all the problem in the book, but on this one, I really have no idea how should I approach it

For a), I guess I need to prove $\delta(G)=k$ somehow, but I can't get any useful info from the definition of $\pi_k$

From 1), can I say that $m(G)< M(K_{k+1})$, if so then part b), can be prove easily, because $\omega(G)$ is just the order of largest complete subgraph in $G$, so if $G$ can't contain $K_{k+1}$ then $\omega(G)<k+1$ but the qual sign really bugging me.

I spent all my weekend working for this problem but getting nowhere, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that some vertex $v$ has degree $\ell<k$. Then $G-v$ has order $n-1$ and size $m-\ell$, so

$$m-\ell\le k(n-1)-\binom{k+1}2=kn-\binom{k+1}2-k$$

by (2), and

$$kn-\binom{k+1}2=n=kn-\binom{k+1}2-k+\ell<kn-\binom{k+1}2\;,$$

which is impossible. Therefore $\delta(G)\ge k$.

Now suppose that $G$ contains an induced copy of $K_{k+2}$. $K_{k+2}$ has $k+2$ vertices and $\binom{k+2}2$ edges, so (2) requires that

$$\binom{k+2}2\le k(k+2)-\binom{k+1}2$$

and hence that

$$\binom{k+2}2+\binom{k+1}2\le k(k+2)\;.$$

But in fact

$$\binom{k+2}2+\binom{k+1}2=\frac{(k+1)(2k+2)}2=(k+1)^2>k(k+2)\;,$$

so $G$ cannot contain an induced copy of $K_{k+2}$, and $\omega(G)\le k+1$.